# Running python script in background EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a `code.py` script that I want to run on my Linux EC2 instance. I want it to run even when the tab of the EC2 instance in my browser is closed, so that the code is running in the background.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "even when the tab of the EC2 instance in my browser is closed"? Are you triggering the script from a browser, or are you running it from a command-line? Do you want it to run as soon as the instance is started, or do you want to start it manually? Please Edit your question to include these details, including what you have tried so far and what problems you have experienced.

Comment: Yes, I meant the EC2 instance tab in a browser and I want it to run manualy. It seems that nohup works fine but my questions is what is the popular/standart way of runnig scripts in EC2 so they run even if I close the instance tab in the browser

Answer (score 5):

this command run your python file on another screen that called `YourScreenName`.

```
screen -dmS YourScreenName python3 code.py
```

if you close EC2 instance tab on your browser, this screen will be running on your server.

for access to this screen you can use this command.

```
screen -r YourScreenName
```

and for quit from this screen use `Ctrl + a + d`

Comment: This is what I've been loking for, thanks!